# Searching for functions in R library

Tags: r, search

New to the forum. Is there a way to search for functions within a particular library in R?

Lets say I would like a list of all the functions in the "graphics" library. How would do that?

If I want to find the specific documentation on the "plot" command I am having trouble finding the documentation when I used the help.search("plot"). It gives me all these other functions from different libraries. I just want to be able to find and narrow down the searches when I look for a particular function.

Comment: For finding methods for a generic function such as `plot`, read  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691812/get-object-methods-r

Comment: You might find an earlier answer of mine helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575098/to-see-all-the-content-not-just-objects-in-a-package-in-r/12576217#12576217

Answer (score 7):

For a listing of all the functions within a package, and links to their documentations, do:

```
help(package = "graphics")
```

That of course assumes that you have installed the package.

---

For your other question:

If you already know the name of the function you are looking for, do not use `help.search("plot")` but `help("plot")`. As the name suggests, `help.search` does a search through all the docs and returns every hit, very much like a Google search.

Finally, know that you can use:

- `?plot`  as a shortcut to `help("plot")`
- `??plot` as a shortcut to `help.search("plot")`.

Comment: Flodel your awsome. Can't thank you enough. Hope you get this message.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example with the package graphics:

```
library(graphics)   #first load the package 
OBJS <- objects("package:graphics")    #use objects to look at all objects
DS <- data(package="graphics")[["results"]][, "Item"]   #find the data sets
OBJS[!OBJS %in% DS]  #compare to data sets
```

Here it is wrapped up as function:

```
funs <- function(package) {
    pack <- as.character(substitute(package))[1]
    require(pack, character.only = TRUE)
    OBJS <- objects(paste0("package:", pack)) 
    DS <- data(package=pack)[["results"]][, "Item"]  
    OBJS[!OBJS %in% DS]  
}

funs(graphics)
```

Answer (score 3):

---

An answer from Brian Ripley on  [R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-April/031666.html)

> `ls("package:ts")`
>
> will list all the objects in the package (I presume package and not 
>   library was meant: a library is a directory holding installed
>   packages).
>
> If you really want to know about the functions (and not all objects)
>   in a  package try
>
> `lsf.str("package:ts")`
>
> which gives the call sequences too.

---

### [unknownR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/unknownR/)

I will also spruik the [unknownR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/unknownR/)  package. There is a nice demonstration [here](http://www.londonr.org/unknownR.pdf).

It is a tool to go search through functions top packages (helps you learn your unknown unknowns)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a function in package `foo`, sometimes `??foo` works quite good.