# methods for an object with length(class)>1

Tags: r, methods

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691812/get-object-methods-r) suggests using `methods(class=class(obj))` to extract the list of methods that are available for an object.

If used on an object where `length(class(obj))>1`, this leads to lots of warnings, e.g.

```
set.seed(101)
a <- matrix(rnorm(20), nrow = 10)
b <- a + rnorm(length(a))
obj <- lm(b ~ a)
```

gives `class(obj)` as `c("lm","mlm")`; `methods(class=class(obj))` gives

> (*many times*)< Warning in grep(pattern, all.names, value = TRUE) :
>     argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   Warning in gsub(name, "", S3reg) :
>     argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>   Warning in sub(paste0("\.", class, "$"), "", row.names(info)) :
>     argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

followed by the results.

It seems (?) that applying `methods(class=...)` to the *last* element of `class(obj)` would work, but I'm interested in alternatives or discussion as to why that is (or is not) correct ...

To clarify, I would like the returned value to be a (preferably unique) character vector, so that I can use something like `if ("foo" %in% allmethods(obj))` to test for the availability of a specified method for the object ...

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
sapply(class(obj), function(x) methods(class = x))
```

Note that the code below gives an error, since argument `generic.function` becomes `mlm`. It must be argument `class` like above.

```
sapply(class(obj), methods)
Error in .S3methods(generic.function, class, parent.frame()) : 
  no function 'mlm' is visible
```

Comment: This gives a list of two objects;  `methods()` returns a slightly complex object of class "MethodsFunction".  Looks like I would need `unique(unlist(sapply(class(obj), function(x) as.character(methods(class = x)))))` (ugh)